# add a placeholder into all objects by specific key

Tags: json, bash

I have an irregular json, e.g.:

```
[
  { "key": 123 },
  [
    { "key": null },
    { "not key": "blah-blah" }
  ]
]
```

What's the most efficient way to add a placeholder record (`"new key": null`) into all objects which have `"key"` record? this is an expected output:

```
[
  { "key": 123, "new key": null },
  [
    { "key": null, "new key": null },
    { "not key": "blah-blah" }
  ]
]
```

Comment: I've edited your output which wasn't valid JSON, can you check I didn't misunderstand what you wanted?

Comment: Looks like a task for `jq`.

Comment: @Aaron, yes, thanks for the edit, it looks good now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `jq` 1.6 and its `walk` function to modify JSON objects recursively :

```
jq 'walk(if type == "object" and has("key") then . + { "new key" : null } else . end)'
```

You can [try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/B8Gj_l8li3).

The following will work on `jq` 1.5 :

```
jq 'def addNewKey: map_values(if type == "object" and has("key") then . + { "new key" : null } elif type=="array" or type=="object" then addNewKey else . end); addNewKey'
```

You can [try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/a-sYOXlOCI).

Comment: `walk` doesn't exist in 1.5 :-(

Comment: @Aaron, thank you, it works on my json! is this a fastest solution? (I have big JSONs to process, typically >1M records)

Comment: @Nerdic I'm in the process of making a solution with basic recursion which might be faster. Using basic text manipulation would certainly be faster in terms of execution time but much less robust and you'd likely have to spend much more time coding to handle the various formats in which your objects are persisted.

Comment: @Nerdic I've updated my answer with an alternative, I can't say which would be faster though. If you test it I'd be interested in the result !

Comment: @Aaron, the newer solution is somewhat 35% faster, unfortunately it does not deliver the same result :(

Comment: @Nerdic is your root an array? I've just noticed my new solution expected that and would mess things a bit if the root was an object. If you can update your sample with data that reproduces the problem I'll see what I can do

Comment: @Aaron, yes, the root of my JSONs is array (though I'd prefer a universal and fast solution). It's impossible to post the file for me (it's too big, plus there's a sensitive info). I'm only checking if the results are the same by piping those to `md5sum` and see that checksums are different  between the two solutions.

Comment: You might want to try using `diff` to have a quick view of what's different, I'm not sure what it could be so it might as well be the `walk` solution that's incorrect.

Comment: @Aaron, I'm able to reduce json to this example: `[{"root":{"key":{"blah":"123"}}}]`, the second solutions fails here, while `walk` works fine.

Comment: @Nerdic Ah yes, I didn't think I'd need to recurse into objects, so my second solution doesn't do it and it certainly explains the 35% speed increase. I've fixed it by I expect it won't be any faster

Comment: @Aaron, yes, now both solutions produce the same checksum, but the second one is somewhat 60% slower. So it looks like `walk` solution is the best